# Check active timers in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Is there a simple way to get a list of all currently waiting timers started with `erlang:send_after`, `erlang:apply_after`, etc. in Erlang?

Comment: Actually there is no `erlang:apply_after` but only `timer:apply_after`. Did you really mean `erlang:` but not `timer:`? Because timers created with `erlang:send_after` and `erlang:start_timer` are completely different and more lightweight than timers created with `timer` module.

Comment: I mean `erlang:` because I already knew how to deal with timers created by `timer:` :)

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: So you want to track also 'after' clauses in receive?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Can you please tell me how to get a list of all currently waiting timers started with timer:apply_after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For debugging purposes you can use `dbg` :).

First create an ets table which will store all timer references.

```
1> ets:new(timer_dbg, ['public', 'named_table', 'bag']).
timer_dbg
```

Then create a dbg handler function, which checks for calls returning from erlang:send_after, and saves the returned timer reference to the table

```
2> Fun = fun({'trace', _Pid, 'return_from', {erlang, send_after, 3}, Ref}, []) ->
2>           ets:insert(timer_dbg, {Ref}), [];
2>          (_Msg, []) ->
2>           []
2>       end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.113037538>
```

Set the function as trace handler. Also enable matching on the call to `erlang:send_after()` on all processes

```
3> dbg:tracer('process', {Fun, []}).
{ok,<0.35.0>}
4> dbg:p('all', 'c').
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,26}]}
5> dbg:tpl(erlang, send_after, [{'_', [], [{'return_trace'}]}]).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1},{saved,1}]}
```

Make some test calls to `erlang:send_after()`

```
6> erlang:send_after(1000, self(), {}).
#Ref<0.0.0.43>
7> erlang:send_after(1000, self(), {}).
#Ref<0.0.0.47>
8> erlang:send_after(1000, self(), {}).
#Ref<0.0.0.51>
```

Finally check that the table does contain those references:

```
9> ets:tab2list(timer_dbg).
[{#Ref<0.0.0.51>},{#Ref<0.0.0.43>},{#Ref<0.0.0.47>}]
```

This way you will store all timer references ever created by any process ever calling `erlang:send_after()`. You can map them over `erlang:read_timer()` to filter the alive timers.

You can trace calls to `send_after` in a similar manner. It is also possible to match on `cancel_timer` and manually remove the cancelled references from the table.

Also, if you don't have a message-intensive application, you should be able to match on messages and/or functions triggered by those timers, and remove the expired references from the list.

Answer (score 5):

thats a hack but use: ets:tab2list(timer_tab). For two timers it holds:

```
  ets:tab2list(timer_tab).                                            
[{{1288384968923398,#Ref<0.0.0.30>},
  timeout,
  {erlang,integer_to_list,[23]}},
 {{23334621698390115688,#Ref<0.0.0.189>},
  timeout,
  {erlang,integer_to_list,[23]}}]
```

Comment: It's useful only for `timer` module timers but not for timers created with `erlang:send_after`, `erlang:apply_after`

Comment: true.. and you mean erlang:send_after only I guess. Is there something like erlang:apply_after any way?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I just copy function names from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code in [erl_bif_timer.c](http://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/dev/erts/emulator/beam/erl_bif_timer.c) I think crash dump is the only place where you can find a list of all BIF timers which were just active. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same necessity of tracking timers today.

It is on production, so I do not want to use dbg. These are erlang:timers so my previous solution is useless.

Instead I analysed nbif_timer parameter from binary_to_list(erlang:system_info(info)).

I believe (have not confirmed yet), it reports memory allocated for timers. On my system x64 it would be 17 words of 8 bytes = 136 bytes.

Monitoring this value clearly shows when system sets high number of timers.

enjoy.

Comment: A pity that there's no direct way, but this should be usable enough for testing purposes. (I plan on integrating it into my property tests.)

Answer (score 0):

you could save the references returned by send_after, aply_after etc and use erlang:read_timer to check if it is still waiting (read_timer returns false if the timer has been canceled or isn't waiting anymore)

Comment: That won't give _all_ timers, but only ones I've explicitly saved.